# Managing multiple solutions with NDepend

Tags: .net, visual-studio, ndepend

Suppose you have two Visual Studio solutions, each of which builds three assemblies - for example:

SolutionA: A1.dll, A2.dll, A3.dll.
SolutionB: B1.dll, B2.dll, B3.dll.

Further, suppose that you have created two corresponding NDepend projects - NDependA and NDependB.

I have two questions to this scenario:

No. 1: Is there an easy way to create a third, combined NDepend project ("NDependAB")?

No. 2: If you add something like A4.dll to SolutionA, do you have to update both NDependA and NDependAB, or is there a way to update NDependAB "automatically"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Just create a new NDepend project and add assemblies of the 2 solutions. This is possible thanks to the link label on the start page: *Analyze : VS solutions and VS projects*

2) No, there is no out-of-the-box way to update the NDepend project from the solution change. This is something we are thinking for the future.